# solar controller

Tags: transistors, resistors

What is the role of R3 and bipolar 2N3904 ?
[image]

Comment: Google gives an excellent description: http://www.instructables.com/id/ARDUINO-SOLAR-CHARGE-CONTROLLER-PWM/?ALLSTEPS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because full circuit description (11 pages) was easily found using Google.

Comment: "The resistor R3 is used as a pull up resistor for gate." and "I used a simple MOSFET driver by using a NPN general purpose transistor.I used 2N3904 but you can use any general purpose transistors like 2N2222 or BC547 etc."

Comment: @jippie: How does that make the question off-topic?

Comment: @EMFields the explanation is in detail on the linked web page, OP doesn't supply any context. Simply by checking the circuit against Google's first hit it is explained that this is a PWM input of a solar charger and every single component is discussed. The question would substantially improve if the article text was quoted in the first place and specifically asked what part of the text is unclear.

Comment: @jippie: I ask again: The OP supplied an annotated schematic and a question relating directly to the topic so, even though you may  find his question not quite up to your "standards",   how could it possibly be  off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

Q1 is a P-channel MOSFET used to connect/disconnect the PV from the circuitry on the downstream side of its [Q1's] drain.  R3 functions to pull Q1's gate up to its source, turning Q1 OFF when T1 is turned off by Cde being low, and T1 is used to pull Q1's gate down to ground, turning Q1 ON, when T1 is turned ON by Cde being driven high.